# Why did Nagato use 6 paths powers only?

Tags: naruto

When pain fought with naruto, he used rikudo powers only (Tendo, Ningendo, Chikusodo, Gakido, Shurado, Jigokudo). Why didn't he use another jutsu such as 5 elements perhaps?

Nagato managed to control and mastered 6 chakra of nature when he was 10 years old. (Mentioned by jiraiya when he realized that chikusodo pain using kuchiyose no jutsu only)

5 elements must be powerful, since if he use 5 elements he's rather like kakuzu. And even kakashi was overwhelmed when he fought 3 kakuzu's jutsu: katon, raiton, and fuuton.

So, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the battle against Hanzo, after Yahiko's suicide, Nagato's inner power awakened, and accidentally summoned Gedo Mazo which instantly impaled its rods inside nagato to get chakra and killed hanzo's men. Then Nagato gets sick, and loose mobility. Then the only long distance power, needed because sickness, is the 6 paths powers.

Source: [Nagato](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Nagato)

Answer (score 1):

When Nagato saw Yahiko die in front of him, he was outraged and lost all control, tapped into his inner powers and accidently summoned the Gedo statue. He ended up killing majority of Hanzo's and Danzo's subordinates, but hanzo escaped using the teleportation jutsu. But when Nagato summoned the Gedo statue, he ended up having the chakra rods being literally stabbed into his back, due to which he became very sick. Also his legs were burnt while fighting Hanzo and his army(this happened due to paper bombs). This forced him to use the 6 paths of pains for the rest of his lives...